# C Program check if sentence is a pangram(sentence that contain all letter's in the alphbet)

Tags: c

I need to get from the user 10 word's and then tell if the sentence that he put is a pangram.
and my code does not work like I was expecting him to work. I doesn't find were the problem is if someone can tell me were is the problem I would really appreciate it
Examples for pangram:
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
"Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf"
and this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_NAMES 10
#define LONG 50

int main()
{
    char names[MAX_NAMES][LONG] = {0};
    bool flage = true;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    char allAlphabet[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    int countAlfa = 0;
    
    printf("Enter up to 10 words, try to make a pangram:\n");
    for(i = 0; (i < MAX_NAMES) && (flage == true); i++)
    {
        fgets(names[i], LONG, stdin);
        names[i][strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;
        for(j = 0; (k < strlen(names[i])) && (j < strlen(allAlphabet)); j++)
        {
            if(names[i][k] == allAlphabet[j])
            {
                countAlfa++;
                allAlphabet[j] = '#';
                k++;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        k = 0;
        if(countAlfa > 25)
        {
            printf("It's a pangram?\n");
            printf("Yes\n");
            flage = false;
        }
    }
    if(countAlfa < 26)
    {
        printf("It's a pangram?\n");
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should convert the characters to lower case, before you access the array, as you will read out of bounds.

Comment: There are other, more efficient algorithms.  Convert each letter to a code value 0..25 (this is C so we count from 0), and increment the appropriate element of an initially all-values zero array.  At the end, check whether any elements of the array are still zero; those correspond to missing letters.  You should move the test for "it is a pangram" outside the loop.  Otherwise, you get told many times over that `Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack noisily` is a pangram — once for each letter in `noisily` (the pangram is complete at the end of `quack`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You commented while I was writing a PoC :D

Comment: I know what @JonathanLeffler suggested as a variant of the _pigeonhole_ algorithm.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Note that רועי אטיאס sets `flage` to false right after successful check for pangram, so no further loops occur.

The problem really seem to be with the `k` variable. The idea seems to be: in __each__ word (name) check __each__ letter of the word against __each__ letter of the alphabet. That's 3x each, but only 2x for in code.

Comment: @veprolet — you're right about it not repeating; my bad.  I would have used a `break` instead of setting a flag to stop the loop.  I still think all the printing should be done after the loop, though.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jonathan Leffler, there is a better way of doing this, which is to use an array of 26 counters initialized to all zeroes.
Then as you go through the letters you increase the corresponding counter, which can be easily accessed using the character value.

This is a small proof of concept. I'm assuming that names will alway have N+1 elements with a NULL pointer at the end

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FALSE (0 != 0)
#define TRUE  (!FALSE)

#define MAX_NAMES 10
#define LONG 50

int main()
{
    char names[MAX_NAMES][LONG] = { "The", "quick", "brown", "Fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "Dog" };
    char flag = TRUE;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char allAlphabet['z' - 'a' + 1] = {0}; // The size is constant and calculated at compile time
    
    while (*names[i] != 0)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(names[i]); j++)
        {
            int letter = tolower(names[i][j]);
            if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
                allAlphabet[letter - 'a']++; // The letter is used to access the counter
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(allAlphabet); i++)
    {
        if (allAlphabet[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("%c is missing\n", i + 'A');
            flag = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("It's a pangram?\n%s\n", flag ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Edit: I was using inverted logic in the last check. I liked it, but it made things harder to understand. Thanks to Roberto Caboni for pointing that out

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/91G

Comment: Correct solution. I'd just remove the confusing `continue` statement by inverting the logic of the check `if (allAlphabet[i] == 0){ flag = FALSE; break;}`

Comment: I know. I just liked that I avoided the braces, but you're right. It's definetily counterintuitive

Comment: It's feasible to argue that the loop `for (j = 0; j < strlen(names[i]); j++)` would be better written as `for (j = 0;names[j] != '\0'; j++)` which runs no risk of running `strlen()` on each iteration.  A good optimizer might spot that it doesn't need to run `strlen()` more than once, but it might not be the best idea to depend on that.  You could handle the test `if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')` with `islower(letter)` or `isalpha(letter)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You mean `names[i][j] != '\0'`. the compiler should optimize `strlen(names[i])` and run it once per `i`. `isalpha(letter)` could be nicer than the explicit comparison, but I'd say it's a matter of taste

Comment: Yes, I do mean to double-subscript the array (so `names[i][j] != '\0'` is what I should have written), @JackLilhammers.  The 'matter of taste' has two issues that make it more complex.  First, some codesets (notably EBCDIC, found on IBM mainframes) do not have contiguous code points for the alphabet, so the range `(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')` might return true for some non-alphabetic characters on such a machine (and simply subtracting `'a'` from the letter is also not sufficient. Second, some codesets and locales might return true for accented characters with `isalpha()`. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Dealing with both issues is fiddly.  For the most part, the EBCDIC issue can be ignored unless you expect to work on mainframes.  The second issue can probably be ignored if your program runs in the C locale (as it should by default).  Or you can argue that using the range `'a'` .. `'z'` is safer.  It might be an idea to use `_Static_assert('z' - 'a' == 25, "Non-contiguous alphabet");` (C11 [§6.7.10 Static assertions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.10)) so the code fails to compile on EBCDIC machines, but it is getting a bit far afield.